# layout_weight=1.0 doesn't have effect

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_label_client_host"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="@string/label_host" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_client_host"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:lines="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I expect `EditText` to fill the whole space remaining by horizontal, but `TextView` and `EditText` get 1/2 of available space. This `LinearLayout` is placed inside of another vertical `LinearLayout`.

Comment: I think you need to remove textview and set hint to EditText.

Comment: Try to set `layout_weight = "1.0"` to LinearLayout (Parent of TextView and EditText).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the

```
   android:ems="10"
```

for all the elements, I tested here and it works.

Answer (score 0):

set the width of the TextView as 0dp....

Comment: If I do this, TextView just disappears.

Comment: set weighSum = 3 (just any int) for the Linear Layout and then add layout_weight = 2 for edit text
and
layout_weight =1 for text view

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:weightSum="1"
>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_label_client_host"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="@string/label_host" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_client_host"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:lines="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to give weight to each component in a layout. That way,it will know what weight is to be given to each of them.So you can try with this:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightsum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_label_client_host"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="@string/label_host" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_client_host"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:lines="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible remove the `android:ems="10"` from the TextView 
and add weight of the TextView to `android:layout_weight="0"`